# "Sets" that don't have enough incoming functions to be sets

Tags: logic, reference-request, computer-science, foundations, type-theory

Under propositions as types, a statement like $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \exists y \in \mathbb{R}(x+y=0),$$ is viewed as a kind of "box" equipped with some methods for constructing elements of that box, which are viewed as proofs of the relevant theorem.

Philosophically at least, this allows us to formalize certain "assignment problems" that can be given to university students; in particular, it allows us to formalize problems of the form

> "Prove $\varphi$."

by writing down the type $\varphi$ and giving it to the student. Their task is then to write down a well-formed term of the relevant type, i.e. a proof.

Suppose we wanted to generalize this kind of thinking so that it encompasses other kinds of problems too. For example:

> "Compute $\tau$."

We want to hold onto the idea that each problem should be a type, and that solutions to that problem should be terms of that type.

If you ponder this for a bit, it quickly becomes clear that we need types that don't have enough "incoming functions" (*constructors*) to be sets.

For instance, to express "compute $31+17$" as the third problem on an assignment, we could try writing down $$\mathrm{Problem}_3 := \bigsqcup_{n:\mathbb{N}_{\mathrm{baseTen}}} U(n) = U(31)+U(17),$$

where $U : \mathbb{N}_{\mathrm{baseTen}} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is the function that turns a base $10$ representation of a natural number into the underlying number. It follows that a term of type $\mathrm{Problem}_3$ consists of a $b \in \mathbb{N}_{\mathrm{baseTen}}$ together with a proof that $U(b) = U(31)+U(17).$

The problem is that its too easy to cheat: just let $$U^{-1} : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}_{\mathrm{baseTen}}$$ denote the relevant inverse function, let $b = U^{-1}(U(31)+U(17)),$ and offer the trivial proof of equality, based on the fact that $U$ and $U^{-1}$ are inverse functions. This allows us to construct a term of type $\mathrm{Problem}_3$ without actually doing any computations. Obviously, this is very bad.

This leads me to believe that we need to be thinking of $\mathbb{N}_{\mathrm{baseTen}}$ from a non-set-theoretic perspective, so that it's possible for $U^{-1}$ to fail to exist, despite that $U$ is obviously a bijection. Said in different words, it seems that we need a foundation of math in which there exist "sets" that don't have enough incoming functions to be sets.

> **Question.** I've heard of "intensional type theory" but I don't know much about it.
>
> My questions are:
>
> - Does intensional type theory allow us to define "sets" that don't have enough incoming functions to be sets?
> - If not, are there any foundations out there that do?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do, but for Problem 3, couldn't you ask that the answer be given in normal form?

Comment: @LucaBressan, well the idea is to write down a type; the student is charged with the problem of writing down a term of that type. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Not really. You say that the function $U^{-1}$ allows the student to answer without doing any computations. But this is because the term $U^{-1}(U(31) + U(17))$ contains $\beta$-redexes. If you ask the student to give an answer that has no $\beta$-redex, i.e. a term in normal form, they will have to actually compute the result. In fact, I don't think you need to use the type $\mathbb{N}_{\mathrm{baseTen}}$ at all, since e.g. $3$ can already be defined as a short-hand for $\mathsf{succ}(\mathsf{succ}(\mathsf{succ}(\mathsf{zero})))$.

Comment: @LucaBressan, I'm not sure I'm following, but what you seem to be saying is that writing "Write down a $\beta$-redex free term of type $\bigsqcup_{n:\mathbb{N}} n = 31+17,$" is enough. I don't really get that. There are no $\beta$-redexes in the term $(31+17,\mathrm{id}_{31+17})$ as far as I can see.

Comment: $31 + 17$ contains a $\beta$-redex, because it's a short-hand for $\mathsf{sum}(31)(17)$, and $\mathsf{sum}$ is defined through the eliminator of the type of natural numbers (e.g., $\mathsf{sum} = \lambda m \in \mathbb{N}. \mathsf{rec}(\lambda n \in \mathbb{N}. n, \lambda n \in \mathbb{N}. \lambda h \in \mathbb{N}. \mathsf{succ}(h(n)), m)$).

Comment: @LucaBressan, maybe. But in real mathematics, it might equally well be the case that $\mathbb{N}$ is defined as the additively-denoted monoid freely generated by a point, in which case it is $\mathrm{succ}$ that's the derived operation. So, I think that any time you're choosing one of these as more fundamental than the other, you should always add some decoration to your notation, like $\mathbb{N}_{S}$ or $\mathbb{N}_{\mathrm{baseTen}}$, which seems to leave us exactly where we began....

Comment: @LucaBressan, I guess one idea would be to distinguish between "types" and "sets," the distinction being that if $X$ is a type, then certain constructors are deemed "irreducible" or "non-shorthands", whereas if $X$ is a mere set, we don't know which is which. But this still leaves us with a distinction between $\mathbb{N}_S$ and $\mathbb{N}$, for example, where the former is a type, and the latter a set.

Comment: @LucaBressan, the other comment I'd make is that if we're using the type $\mathbb{N}_S$, then $48$ fails to be in normal form, because its really shorthand for $40+8$, which requires some computation to get into successor form. So the distinction between $\mathbb{N}_S$ and $\mathbb{N}_{\mathrm{baseTen}}$ is really quite important.

Comment: I should add the I don't wish to sound bombastic or conceited. If you think I'm just confused, please say so.

Comment: $48$ is a shorthand for $\mathsf{succ}(\mathsf{succ}(\ldots \mathsf{succ}(0) \ldots))$ with 48 $\mathsf{succ}$'s, not for $40 + 8$ (or $30 + 18$, or...). There are very precise rules for short-hands. There is no reason to use many different types of natural numbers, the usual inductive type with $\mathsf{zero}$ and $\mathsf{succ}$ is exactly what you need if you want your student to compute $31 + 17$.

Comment: @LucaBressan, I accept that what you're saying is true in the current way of doing things, but I'm not convinced the current way of doing things is very good. For example, to find out whether or not $3$ divides a number like $178$, we can argue as follows: $$3 \mid 178 \iff 3 \mid 1+7+8 \iff 3 \mid 16 \iff \bot$$ But these kinds of computations are dependent on the base we're using. So if the currently-dominant framework says that $48$ is shorthand for $\mathsf{succ}(\mathsf{succ}(\ldots \mathsf{succ}(0) \ldots)),$ then lets just say I'm skeptical.

Comment: @LucaBressan, do you agree that this is important, or am I just confused?